CakePHP 5: how to get total number of records retrieved with pagination
I'm migrating from cakephp 4 to 5.x, and in an API I need to return the pagination data.
In cakephp 4.x
$paging = $this->request->getAttribute("paging");
$paginacao = [];
foreach ($paging as $p):
  $paginacao = [
    "count" => $p["count"],
    "current" => $p["current"],
    "perPage" => $p["perPage"],
    "page" => $p["page"],
    "requestedPage" => $p["requestedPage"],
    "pageCount" => $p["pageCount"],
    "start" => $p["start"],
    "end" => $p["end"],
    "prevPage" => $p["prevPage"],
    "nextPage" => $p["nextPage"],
  ];
endforeach;

In cakephp 5 ?

In CakePhp5 you have a PaginatorHelper accesible when you paginate a result set. In order to user it you have to load it on your AppView like this :
$this->loadHelper('Paginator');

or
$this->loadHelper('Paginator', ['templates' => 'paginator-templates']);

And you can user it in dis way on you controllers (example) :
$this->set('articles', $this->paginate($this->Articles));

or
$query = $this->Articles->find('published')->contain('Comments');
$this->set('articles', $this->paginate($query));

You can change the Paginator options :
protected array $paginate = [
        'limit' => 25,
        'order' => [
            'Articles.title' => 'asc',
        ],
    ];

And you can retrieve the total like this :
$this->Paginator->total();

More documentation :
Pagination CakePhp5
PaginatorHelper CakePhp5
